# Find the differential equation of all straight lines in a plane including the case when lines are non-horizontal/vertical

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, differential-geometry

Find the differential equation of all lines in a 2-D plane.

**My Attempt**

For horizontal lines,we have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

For vertical lines,we have $$\frac{dx}{dy}=0$$

For non-vertical lines(includes the case when line is horizontal),we have $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$$

For non-horizontal lines(includes the case when it is vertical),we have $$\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=0$$

Similarly,can we have a single differential equation in which all the above cases are accounted for

Comment: Do you allow for vector-valued ODE?

Comment: If an equation is possible then it should be allowed i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can neither express all lines in terms of a function $y(x)$ nor express all lines in terms of a function $x(y)$, since in each case there are lines that aren't described by such functions. This is a matter of the form in which you represent the functions, not of the differential equations that you impose on that form.

All lines can be represented in the form $(x(s),y(s))$, where $s$ is an arc length parameter, and in this representation the differential equation for lines is $\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm ds^2}(x(s),y(s))=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the differential equation $y''=0$ specifies all lines in the $xy$-plane, include horizontal and slant except vertical lines. This is because $y$ is a **function** but the line $x=a$ doesn't show any function to have a differential equation form.